# XMEGA Setting up SPI and reading WHO_AM_I_A register from LSM330 device

Tags: c, avr, spi, microprocessors

So I am having a tough time setting up my SPI, and getting it to work with the LSM330 device to read accelerometer data. I'm simply setting up the SPI system, and trying to use that to read the WHO_AM_I_A register to confirm that it is working and all I'm getting back is 0xff rather than 0x40.

Here is my code:

**main.c**

```
#include <avr/io.h>
#include "LSM330.h"
#include "spi.h"
#include "CLK.h"
#include "accel.h"

int main(void) {
    //set clock
    set32MhzClock();

    //first set SPI slave selects for accel gyro to false(high)
    PORTF.OUTSET = PIN4_bm | PIN3_bm;

    //set serial system of SPI
    PORTA_OUTCLR = PIN4_bm;

    //init SPI
    spi_init();

    //reset LSM330 accel by sending 0x01 to CTRL_REG4_A
    accel_write(0x01, CTRL_REG4_A);

    //trying to read from WHO_AM_I_A reg
    uint8_t whoAreYou = accel_read(WHO_AM_I_A);
    printf(whoAreYou);
}
```

**accel.h**

```
#include "LSM330.h"
#include "spi.h"

void accel_write(uint8_t reg_addr, uint8_t data) {
    //make slave select signal LOW
    PORTF_OUTCLR = PIN3_bm;

    //set sensor_sel
    PORTF_OUTSET = PIN2_bm;

    //first write reg_addr, w/ RW=0 and MS=0
    uint8_t writeResult = spi_write(reg_addr);

    //then write data byte
    spi_write(data);

    return;
}
```

**spi.h**

```
void spi_init(void) {
    //set correct pins as outputs and inputs
    PORTF.DIRSET = PIN7_bm | PIN5_bm | PIN4_bm | PIN3_bm; //SCK, MOSI, SSG, SSA as outputs
    PORTF.DIRCLR = PIN6_bm; //MISO as input

    //set up SPI as master
    SPIF.CTRL = SPI_ENABLE_bm | SPI_MASTER_bm | SPI_MODE_3_gc | SPI_PRESCALER_DIV16_gc;

   //clear spi interrupt flag by reading spsr and spdr
   SPIF_STATUS;
   SPIF_DATA;

   return
}

uint8_t spi_write(uint8_t dataIn) {
    //write data
    SPIF.DATA = dataIn;

    //wait for transmission to complete
    while(!(SPIF_STATUS & SPI_IF_bm));
    return SPIF.DATA;
}

uint8_t spi_read(vodi) {
    return spi_write(0xFF);
}
```

And that's all I have. Have tried many things, and can't seem to get this thing to work. It seems like SPI is working because it's not getting stuck up in any of the while loops when writing data.

Answer (score 0):

Without going too much into the details, there is definitely something wrong here:

```
//reset LSM330 accel by sending 0x01 to CTRL_REG4_A
accel_write(0x01, CTRL_REG4_A);
```

But the declaration of your function is as follows:

```
void accel_write(uint8_t reg_addr, uint8_t data)
```

It seems you are setting register 0x01 to value of CTRL_REG4_A.